# My android apk can not run on android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aclientz.aclientzcds"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

I develop an android application in android studio.Created a signed buindle apk and install my phone (android 5.0) work perfactly but its not working in andoid 5.0+ version. How to avoid this problems, pLease give suggestion

Comment: give the Logtrace please!!

Comment: debug your code best way otherwise no idea from here.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: are you getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Please Check for runtime permission if you have any permission uses camera or contact which require runtime permission ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))

or for checking purpose please set your targetsdk to 22